# Rails 4: Open Graph Meta-tags not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I set up the [meta-tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags) gem, and I added Open Graph metatags as follows:

```
<% set_meta_tags title: 'Sortyu Image',
                description: @photo.description, 
                og: {
                    title:     'Sort images, choose what you like the most of an image',
                    type:      'website',
                    url:       "#{photo_url(@photo)}",
                    site_name: 'Sortyu',
                    image:     [{
                                    _: "#{@photo.file.url(:medium)}",
                                    width: @width,
                                    height: @height,
                    }]
                } %>
```

This is generating this kind of Open Graph metatags on my pages:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Sort images, choose what you like the most of an image">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://sortyu-staging.herokuapp.com/photos/43">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Sortyu">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sortyu.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/files/000/000/043/medium/valida.png?1488596412">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="626">
```

I added this like 4 days ago for my pages, but Facebook doesn't get any of my Open Graph metatags, I have checked the format of my metatags and it seems to be right... However on the [Open Graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing) says that I haven't provide anything:

```
Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing: The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
Inferred Property: The "go:image" property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

As you can see above, those properties are indeed provided... So I don't know what's going on... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No man, I never found the issue

Comment: Did you put the `fb:app_id` property in there?

Comment: fb:app_id? could you provide an example of this meta tag?